Boost converter compensation RC network
I am using the TPS61175 as a boost converter, outputting 15V from a 6V, 0.8A input. According to the datasheet, component values and layout are detailed, but I cannot find any useful information on deriving the values for R3 and C4(RC network connected to the COMP pin).
The closest reference to the COMP pin and components R3 and C4 I have found is page 17, which details the following:

I can see that equations 19-22 mention at least one(or both) those components, but unlike the other components(i.e. input/output capacitors, voltage set resistors), I cannot find anything that details the values for R3 and C4.
For reference, the recommended design is below:

Values for every other component except for R3 and C4 are provided, whether through formulas or graphs.
How do I derive the values for R3 and C4?

Before attempting to compensate a converter, you need to obtain its control-to-output transfer function. In other words, you have to plot the ac response of the power stage, including the modulator inside the controller. Please check my ready-made templates, there are examples of boost converters which work on the free demo version of SIMPLIS. Once you have the transfer function, you can have a look at this APEC seminar.
